# How i can activate cpu.cfs_quota_us in Cgroup?

Tags: kernel, cpu, cgroup

How I can activate `cpu.cfs_quota_us` function in Cgroup on Debian Jessie (raspberry pi 4.1.13-v7+ kernel)? This file not exist in cpu controller after creating the group and I didn't find how I can change this neither data sheet Red Hat nor kernel specification of cgroups.

In ubuntu kernel 3.13.0-70-generic this file exist.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

I am likely bad looking)

Comment: Этот сайт предназначен для вопросов на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопросы должны задаваться на русском языке. / Russian, do you speak it?